# How to make routing for more than 2 waypoints in leaflet

Tags: javascript, ajax, routes, leaflet

I am making a route between 2 points in leaflet,i want to make it for more than two points,these points are varien (not constant) taken from ajax from the database how can i make that?

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"farmers_geojson.php",
            data:{'FarmersID': Farmer} ,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                geojsonFarmLayer = L.geoJson(
                response,
                    {
                        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) 
                        {
                             Frmlat=feature.properties._coordinates__latitude;
                             Frmlng=feature.properties._coordinates__longitude;
                             layer.bindPopup('<label>Farmer Name:</label>' + feature.properties.nick_name_ + '<br><label>Farmer ID:</label>' + feature.properties.Farm_id);
                         }
                    }).addTo(mymap);

                //routing between points

                var routeControl = L.Routing.control({
                }).addTo(mymap)
                var route = new Array();
                route.push(new L.LatLng(lng, lat));
                route.push(new L.LatLng(Frmlng, Frmlat));
                route.push(new L.LatLng(8.69395, 153.0986));

                routeControl.setWaypoints(route);//NOW the points appears but no route
     }
        })
```

Comment: Just add more `latLng`s to the `waypoints` array.

Comment: i want to make it as an `array` as the number of `waypoints` is variable not constant

Comment: Then use an array variable; you don't have to use an array literal. And if you need to alter the waypoints after creating the control, just call `setWaypoints`, passing an array - either a literal or a variable. It's all in the [docs](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/).

Comment: @cartant: i edited my code ,please check it.